# Number of groups possible we can compose

Tags: combinatorics

The question is the following:

A group of 20 people, 12 men and 8 women, need to take a bus for an excursion by misunderstandings, a bus with only 10 seats is presented and 6 men and 4 women will take part in this excursion. If we suppose that Mr. A and Madam B can not go in the same excursion how many groups can we make?

My proposition is the following:
$
\binom{11}{6} \binom{8}{4} 
+ \binom{12}{6} \binom{7}{4} 
+ \binom{11}{6} \binom{7}{4}
$.

But according to my professor the right answer is:
$
\binom{11}{5} \binom{7}{4} 
+ \binom{11}{6} \binom{7}{3} 
+ \binom{11}{6} \binom{7}{4}$.

Which one is right with explanation please?

Comment: I edited your post to use MathJax formatting (learn more formatting [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)). Please edit your post to fill in the missing number in your suggested solution and explain where each piece came from!

Comment: Also, there are lots of good tips about asking a good question on this site [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). You're more likely to get good answers if you ask good questions!

Comment: @SammyBlack I think that the posting (except the poor Math formatting, which has been remedied) is a reasonably high quality posting.  The (wrong) answer can only be explained by the OP (i.e. original poster) working privately on the problem, posting their result, and making a subtle analytical mistake.  As I see it, their posting does not need to be improved and therefore is eligible to be answered.

Answer (score 3):

Professor is correct.  You accidentally over-counted.

Since your posting has a typo, I presumed that you (consistently) intended

$$\left[\binom{11}{6} \times \binom{8}{4}\right] + \left[\binom{12}{6} \times \binom{7}{4}\right] + \left[\binom{11}{6} \times \binom{7}{4}\right].\tag1 $$

Consider the first term in (1) above, which represents that Mr A does not go, and Madam B may or may not go.  This first term includes those situations where neither Mr A nor Madam B go.

Similarly, consider the second term in (1) above, which represents that Madam B does not go, and Mr A may or may not go.  This second term also includes those situations where neither Mr A nor Madam B go.

Those situations where neither Mr A nor Madam B go are also represented by the third term in (1) above.  So, these situations are counted three times, instead of only being counted once.

Now, consider the professor's answer:

$$\left[\binom{11}{5} \times \binom{7}{4}\right] + \left[\binom{11}{6} \times \binom{7}{3}\right] + \left[\binom{11}{6} \times \binom{7}{4}\right].\tag2 $$

In (2) above:

- The first term represents the situation where Mr A **definitely** goes, and madam B **definitely** does not go.
- The second term represents the situation where madam B **definitely** goes, and Mr A **definitely** does not go.
- The third term represents the situation where it is definite that neither Mr A nor madam B go.

So, the professor has successfully organized all of the satisfying choices into three **mutually exclusive** possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative method you can use to test which answer is correct.

There are $\binom{12}{6} \times \binom 84$ *unconstrained* ways to select $6$ men and $4$ women for the excursion.  However, of those, $\binom{11}{5} \times \binom 73$ are forbidden because they include Mr. A and Madam B.

So the correct answer is $\binom{12}{6} \times \binom 84 - \binom {11}{5} \times \binom 73$.